# Chain two parsers in Haskell (Parsec)

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

Parsec provides an operator to choose between two parsers:

```
(<|>)
  :: Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
     -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m a
```

Is there a similar function to chain two parsers? I didn't find one with the same signature using Hoogle.

---

As an example, let's say I want to parse any word optionally followed by a single digit. My first idea was to use `>>` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
parser = many1 letter >> optional (fmap pure digit)
```

I used `fmap pure` in order to convert the digit to an actual string and thus match the parsed type of `many1 letter`. I don't know if it is useful.

Comment: `>>` or `*>` *do* sequence parsers, through their `Monad`/`Applicative` instances, but they only return the result of the second parser. (Likewise, `<*` returns the result of the first; and as a convenience, `x <$ p` returns a constant value `x`, equivalent to the common pattern `p *> pure x`). You don’t strictly *need* the `fmap pure` there, since the result types don’t need to match, but it may often be more convenient to combine results using `<$>` and `<*>` (as in @SergeyKuz1001’s answer) if the types are the same.

Comment: It's a very clear explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```hs
parser = (++) <$> many1 letter <*> option "" (fmap pure digit)
```

This is equivalent to:

```hs
parser = pure (++) <*> many1 letter <*> option "" (fmap pure digit)
```

`option [] (fmap pure digit)` return empty string if the parser `digit` have failed and a string from one digital char otherwise.

You can also use do-notation for more readable code:

```hs
parser = do
    s1 <- many1 letter
    s2 <- option "" (fmap pure digit)
    return (s1 ++ s2)
```

Comment: I guess `option ""` would be a little clearer but anyway it's a great answer, thanks!